# Как получить сигнал в QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qlistwidget

Проблема такова: не могу подключить сигнал в `QListWidget`.

**main.py**:

```
import sys   
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from Design import EdWiwndow


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Window = EdWiwndow()
        self.Window.setupUi(self)
        self.Window.Button_Edit.clicked.connect(self.Edit_on)
        self.Window.Button_Save.clicked.connect(self.Save_on)
        self.Window.Button_Save.hide()

        self.Window.item.itemClicked.connect(self.Print) # Проблема в этой строке!

        self.show()
    
    def Edit_on(self):
        self.Window.Button_Edit.hide()
        self.Window.Button_Save.show()

    def Save_on(self):
        # Место для сохранения входных данных
        self.Window.Button_Save.hide()
        self.Window.Button_Edit.show()

    def Print(self):
        print('+')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Window()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class EdWiwndow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(705, 522)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 261, 491))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.Button_Edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_Edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Button_Edit.setFont(font)
        self.Button_Edit.setObjectName("Button_Edit")
        self.Button_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_Save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 10, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Button_Save.setFont(font)
        self.Button_Save.setObjectName("Button_Save")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.Winy =MainWindow
        self.Winy.statusBar()
        self.menubar = self.Winy.menuBar()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        self.item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "The First"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.Button_Edit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.Button_Save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
```

Comment: `self.Window.item.itemClicked -> self.Window.listWidget.itemClicked` замените. Это сигнал списка, а не элемента списка. И приводите текст ошибки в вопросе, а не просто указывайте строку, вызывающую исключение.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо) А можно ли обраться именно к определенному элементу из списка?

Comment: `def Print(self): -> def Print(self, item):` - ссылка на элемент, по которому кликнули передается в слот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То о чем вы спрашиваете, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5           import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from Design import EdWiwndow


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Window = EdWiwndow()
        self.Window.setupUi(self)

        self.Window.Button_Edit.clicked.connect(self.Edit_on)
        self.Window.Button_Save.clicked.connect(self.Save_on)

        self.Window.Button_Save.hide()

        #self.Window.item.itemClicked.connect(self.Print) # Пробллема в этой строке!
        self.Window.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.Print)

        # +++
        self.initListWidget()

        self.show()

    def Edit_on(self):
        self.Window.Button_Edit.hide()
        self.Window.Button_Save.show()

    def Save_on(self):
        # Место для сохранения входных данных
        self.Window.Button_Save.hide()
        self.Window.Button_Edit.show()

    def Print(self):
        itemNumber = self.Window.listWidget.currentRow()
        item       = self.Window.listWidget.item(itemNumber)
        print("item = `{}`, itemNumber = `{}`".format(item.text(), itemNumber))

    # +++
    def initListWidget(self):
        """ Заполняем QListWidget, если нужно и установить курсрсор в нужную позицию """

        self.initList = ["Это", "заполнитель", "виджета", "QListWidget", "по умолчанию"]
        self.Window.listWidget.addItems(self.initList)
        self.Window.listWidget.setCurrentRow(3)        # установить курсрсор в нужную позицию. Например 3.         


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Window()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]